# Including a class.h file in a *.idl file gives errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, corba, idl, omniorb

I have some simple Interface in Corba:

```
#ifndef __INTERFFACE_IDL__
#define __INTERFFACE_IDL__

import User.h;

interface Interfface {  void fun(in User u); };

#endif
```

And i also have simple C++ class User.h with private fields: firstName, lastName, age and getters and setters. I use omniORB, and try translate my interface to C++ file :

```
    omniidl -bcxx interface.idl
```

but it gives me those errors:

```
omniidl -bcxx interface.idl
interface.idl:4: Syntax error in definition
interface.idl:4: Syntax error in abstract valuetype
interface.idl:8: Error in look-up of 'User': 'User' not found
omniidl: 3 errors.
```

User.h is in the same folder that interface.idl is. What's wrong?

This code:

```
#ifndef __INTERFFACE_IDL__
#define __INTERFFACE_IDL__

**import test/User.h;**

interface Interfface {  void fun(in User u); };

#endif
```

gives same errors...

**EDIT:**

my User.h file:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

class User
{
    private :
            string firstName;
            string lastName;
            int age;
    public :
            string getFirstName();
            string getLastName();
            int getAge();
            void setFirstName(string);
            void setLastName(string);
            void setAge(int);
};
```

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about something inside `User.h`, so you'll have to post that.

Comment: @Useless : Ok, I posted the User.h code in my first post

Comment: IDL is not C++.  You will have to write an interface definition for IUser as well.

Comment: @Hans Passant: but how to do this? I would also like to add to my User class operator ==, = and copying constructor. How to write it in IDL? And how to include IUser in interface.idl later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` is not valid IDL. Perhaps you meant `#include`? But your `User.h` file is in C++. It needs to be in IDL.